# What does 'Vacuum' do in Menial's Base 2 application?

Tags: sqlite, mac-os-x

I've had a look at the help documentation for *Base 2*, as well as Menial's product page, but haven't found an answer there. I've even clicked on the <kbd>vacuum</kbd> button and not noticed any change. What does that button do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a [**Menial Base 2**](http://menial.co.uk/base/) person

[VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) is a sqlite operation for defragmenting tables and tablespaces. It also helps reclaim diskspace.

It defragments all sqlite tables by copying data from the sqlite tables to a temp tablespace. The VACUUM operation will then swap out the old tablespace and use the new one. Database pages lost due to DELETEs and UPDATEs will no longer exist.

[MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/) also uses sqlite tables for collecting database statistics and features a VACUUM operation.

Comment: So it's analogous to defragmenting the database?

Comment: Yes. This concept is also in PostgrSQL : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html